# How to get number of weeks total in last 30 day

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get number of weeks in last 30 days (4 or 5).

I have a query which returns a number. I want to divide this number with "count" of weeks in last 30 days...

For example:

```
trunc(sysdate,'W') --is not option, because it's a week number..
```

Today is 29.10.2019. Sysdate-30 is 29.09.2019. 
   I want to know how many weeks were between sysdate & sysdate -30.

What's the simplest solution for this ?

Comment: Do you want the number of whole weeks? Or the number of distinct week numbers? Or something else?

Comment: @APC whole weeks.. but if u know a "simplier" solution for this (then the answer is) i'll undo the acceptation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I understood the question; use `iw` format mask, not `w`:

```
SQL> select to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'iw')) - to_number(to_char(sysdate - 30, 'iw')) result
  2  from dual;

    RESULT
----------
         5

SQL>
```